# Как найти индекс равенства суммы левых и правых элементов?

Tags: python

Задача: дан список чисел  `[4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 9]`, необходимо найти индекс элемента, в котором сумма левых и сумма правых элементов будет равна: 4 + 1 + 7 = 12 и 3 + 9 = 12.

Ничего кроме этого не пришло на ум:

```
def midpoint_sum(a):
    ans = []
    sum_a = 0
    for i in a:
        sum_a += i
        ans.append(sum_a)
    ans2 = []
    sum_a2 = 0
    for i in a[::-1]:
        sum_a2 += i
        ans2.append(sum_a2)
    ans3 = [i for i in range(len(ans[1:])) if ans[i] in ans2[1:]]
    return (ans3[-1])
```

А в итоге еще и ответы не правильные получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

здесь удобнее всего использовать срезы и встроенную функцию [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
lst = [4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 9]

res = 0
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    if sum(lst[:i]) == sum(lst[i+1:]):
        res = i
        break
print(res)
```

PS если `res == 0` - это значит условие равенства не выполняется для **любого** индекса списка.

Comment: Благодарю! Сам бы не догадался:(

Answer (score 2):

Вот так например:

```
list =  [4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 9]
el = next(id for id,x in enumerate(list) if sum(list[0:id]) == sum(list[id+1:]))
print(el)
```

UPD: Подсмотрел в ответе @MaxU и упростил немного

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать так (в одну строчку без дополнительных функций или развёрнутых циклов):

```
lst = [4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 9]

index = max(pos if sum(lst[:pos]) == sum(lst[pos + 1:]) else -1 for pos in range(len(lst)))

print(index)
```

в этом случае, если такого индекса не существует, то будет возвращено -1

Answer (score 1):

Если препод спросит - "А оптимально ли квадратичное решение?", то можно использовать алгоритм с линейной сложностью

(кстати, ваша задумка тоже линейная, только память тратит, чего можно избежать, да и нужно было сравнивать определённые элементы списков сумм)

```
a = [4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 9]
rs = sum(a)  #сумма справа
ls = 0       #сумма слева
idx = -1
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    rs -= x
    if rs == ls:
        idx = i
    ls += x
print(idx)
```